# flexslider stops sliding on touch and dives images in two ios phone gap

Tags: ios, cordova, slider, touch, flexslider

If youre working with small slide you will notice they often stall halfways thru the slide. im using slide and not fade. Ive tested this on the basic flexslider example there is. It doenst matter if its a big og small slide if you slide the picture to 50% and you leave your finger from the slide, going straight down, then the image is stuck with 50% of to images.. Is this a bug or is there a solution? tested on ios 6 phone gap

edit it doenst have to be 50% you its everywhere u start sliding images and move the finger out of the slider then the sliding animation is stopped and youre stuck with something of two images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Its currently a bug according to github A minor bug with no one to fix it anytime soon.. However i experienced severals flicker bugs when creating a slider on a transformed moved div...

therefor the solution for me was use iosslider instead. Its perfect! ive tried all sliders out there this one does it all with no bugs!!!.. Its free for personal use however not free for commercial :/ anyways its the best and there really isnt an alternative to what i need a slider for.

Say thank you with +1 if you went ahead and downloaded iosslider :) You will be satisfied i promise!